# recyclerview and firebase can't compile

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database

Because I want to use RecyclerView and firebase ,I have read a lot about firebase database adapter on recyclerview, but I'm not sure if I have any error in my source code. It doesn't compile. Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Move.java

```
public class Movie {
private String name;

public Movie(String name) {
}

public Movie(String name, String tel) {
    this.name = name;
//    this.tel = tel;

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
   }

  }
```

MoviesAdapter.java

```
  public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<Movie> moviesList;

public MoviesAdapter() {

}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title, year, genre;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
    //    genre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_phone);

    }
}


public MoviesAdapter(List<Movie> moviesList) {
    this.moviesList = moviesList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Movie movie = moviesList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(movie.getName());
  //  holder.genre.setText(movie.getTel());
}

@Override
  public int getItemCount() {
       return moviesList.size();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<String> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
private MoviesAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter();
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    DatabaseReference reference_contacts = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("contacts");
    reference_contacts.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             movieList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren() ){

                movieList.add(ds.child("name").getValue().toString());
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    }


}
```

Comment: Where is the compilation error? Please show your gradle file if you are missing the firebase and recyclerview dependencies

Comment: post stacktrace

Comment: Please add the error code so, we can give the appropriate solution. As per your code snippet here in your model class, you not defined an empty constructor. So if you get the error like  Missing a constructor with no argument then please defined empty constructor first. Good Luck!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of them work fine together. There is no dependency between them. Your issue probably comes from your gradle files.
What kind of errors do you get ?

Please make sure to use the latest buildToolsVersion in your gradle file :

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "your.package.name"
    minSdkVersion XX
    targetSdkVersion 25
}
```

and add the following dependencies :

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
```

Make sure the dependencies if your root gradle file are up to date :

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
```

You have everything here :

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup